# Import and Export Data plus schema using SQLDeveloper 3.0.04

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

i am newbie to oracle and i like to export database from remote database and import it on local machine. eOn both machines i have oracle 10.2.

I need to know how to export/import schema and data from oracle 10.2 using SQLDeveloper 3.0.0.4.

To export from remote database, i have used export Tool-> Database Export ->  export wizard.
and at the end i have got only sql file with DDL and DML statements but somewhere in file it is written

```
"Cannot render Table DDL for object XXX.TABLE_NAME with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator error.
```

I have ignored previously mentioned message and tried to run those DDL and DML statements but all this ended up with errors.

Is it possible that all this tied with read-only database user?  More over, i dont find any table under tables but also tables under other users in SqlDeveloper.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try it manually for one table as a test: select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;  If that doesn't work, try a simple: describe MY_TABLE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test, can you select one object in the tree, and navigate to the script panel? SQLDEV also uses DBMS_METADATA to generate those scripts.

Also, as a work-around, try using DataPump to export and import your data. It will be much more efficient for moving around larger schemas.

Your note about not seeing tables under indicates your schema doesn't actually own any tables. You may be working with synonyms that allow you to query objects as if they are in your account. You could be running into a privilege issue, but your error message doesn't indicate that. Error messages often come in bunches, and the very first one is usually the most important.

If you could try using the EXPORT feature say against a very simple schema like SCOTT as a test, this should indicate whether there is a problem with your account settings or with the software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with SQL Developer 3.0 but with version 3.1 you can follow this:

[SQL Developer 3.1 Data Pump Wizards (expdp, impdp)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-developer-31-data-pump-wizards.php)